# How to connect amazon linux by ssh

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I would like to login to `amazon linux` EC2 instance

I tried like below command.

`chmod 600 20200223.pem`

`ssh i 20200223.pem ec2-user@ec2-3-133-82-108.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

But the response is like this,

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname i: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

How can I fix it? I guess the command is correct.

Thanks

Comment: there should be a dash: `ssh -i ...`

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the instance using SSH.

Bash

*Connect to the instance using SSH. The instance is running a relatively recent version of Amazon Linux 2:*

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-0-15 ~]$ uname -srv
Linux 4.14.104-95.84.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 21 12:40:53 UTC 2019
```

Bash:

*Use the yum command to install the ec2-instance-connect RPM package.*

```
$ sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ec2-instance-connect.noarch 0:1.1-9.amzn2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

........

Installed:
    ec2-instance-connect.noarch 0:1.1-9.amzn2                                                                                                     

Complete!
```

This RPM installs a few scripts locally and changes the AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorizedKeysCommandUser configurations in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. If you are using a configuration management tool to manage your sshd configuration, install the package and add the lines as described in the documentation.

With ec2-instance-connect installed, you are ready to set up your users and have them connect to instances. Maybe, [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/) can help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering,I couldn't figure out why my command didn't work well..I am mac user, so I treid `$ brew install ec2-instance-connect Error: No available formula with the name "ec2-instance-connect" `   It seems didn't work well.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. @Heisenberg